# Distance between edge of text and edge of button?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the distance between the left edge of the text on a button and the actual edge of the button?

Comment: doesn't `getPaddingLeft()` work?

Comment: Is your text of the button centered aligned(vertical and horizontal) in the parent?

Comment: post some specifics results that show why it is  off.